# Android - LinearLayout : How to add autospace beetween items to fill the layout horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, gravity, autofill

How to you make 4 fixed size buttons in an horizontal LinearLayout fill the space of that layer horizontally, letting the Android put the needed space betetween those buttons to fill that space ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you searching for something like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to make those 4 buttons take equal space in a horizontal LinearLayout, if so, then add: `android:layout_weight="1"` in the XML layout, for each 4 buttons.

Comment: No, that makes the buttons bigger. I want the space beetween those buttons to adapt and grow to fill the space. I want the space beetween the buttons to act as filler.